# How can i click on an item that is freshly created with an automated test?

Tags: katalon-studio

How can I click on an item that is freshly created with an automated test using katalon?

In my katalon script I am adding one record and immediately I want to edit that record. So I want to identify the new one among old records.

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_MEDICALHUB  Sales/button_SAVE'))         //here I am saving 

WebUI.check(???????) //here I want to select checkbox to edit

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_MEDICALHUB  Sales/i_Sales_fa fa-pencil'))
```

checkbox is not checked

Comment: your issue is checkbox is displaying but it's not checking, right?

Comment: Thanks for reply. my issue is how to replace ???? with  freshly created record WebUI.check(???????)

Answer (score 0):

before try to check

Use this:

```
WebUI.waitForElementPresent(findTestObject('checkobx'), waitTime)
```

Comment: I am executing Test Suit. It contains creation, Edit and Delete test cases, So before running Test Suit check box will not exists. once executing creation test case only check box generated dynamically. In my next test case i need to check newly generated checkbox to edit. -- How can I click  an item that is freshly created with an automated test using katalon?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to wait for the element to be rendered, you will need to wait not only for it to be present (present in DOM) but also clickable:

```
WebUI.waitForElementClickable(findTestObject('Object Repository/checkbox element'), 30)
```

More info on [Katalon Docs page](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-wait-for-element-clickable.html#description).

Comment: I am executing Test Suit. It contains creation, Edit and Delete test cases, So before running Test Suit check box will not exists. once executing creation test case only check box generated dynamically. In my next test case i need to check newly generated checkbox. that checkbox is visible and clickable but i don't have Object information  -- How can I click  an item that is freshly created with an automated test using katalon?

Comment: Ok, so part of the creation test should also be getting info on the generated object. How can a regular user see that the new element has been created?